# Twitter API Request easily returns Request Limit

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am using Twitter API to retrieve retweeters for my tweets. The code involves 2 For-Next loops, which theoritically works. My problem is that the below codes is vulnerable to "Request Limit Exceeded" problems and on the 3rd try of running the scripts, I encountered the said limit error.

May I ask for your advise/comments guys as I might just be doing it all wrong? The codes are below:

```
<?php
$urlUserTimeLine = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
$getfield = '?count=200&screen_name=' . $AuthenticatedScreenName . '&since_id=' . $TweetID;
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$UserTimeLineResponse = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                        ->buildOauth($urlUserTimeLine, $requestMethod)
                        ->performRequest();                                             

$UserTimeLineResponseJSONDecoded =  json_decode($UserTimeLineResponse, true);
foreach ($UserTimeLineResponseJSONDecoded as $key_post_to_url => $jsons_post_to_url) {
    foreach ($jsons_post_to_url as $key_post_to_url2 => $jsons_post_to_url2) {
        if($key_post_to_url2=="id"){
            $TweetID2 = $jsons_post_to_url2;

            $urlReTweets = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/' . $TweetID2 . '.json';
            $ReTweeterResponse =    $twitter->setGetfield($getfieldReTweets)
                                    ->buildOauth($urlReTweets, $requestMethodReTweets)
                                    ->performRequest();

            $ReTweeterResponseJSONDecoded =  json_decode($ReTweeterResponse, true);
            foreach ($ReTweeterResponseJSONDecoded as $key_post_to_url => $jsons_post_to_url) {
                foreach ($jsons_post_to_url['user'] as $key_post_to_url2 => $jsons_post_to_url2) {
                    if($key_post_to_url2=="screen_name"){
                            echo $jsons_post_to_url2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you not caching the results in your database and checking against it every, I do not know, 1 hour ?

Comment: Hi David. Yes, that's actually one of our alternatives. What I am doubtful is how I created my codes. Not sure if I am doing it right, or there is an easy and optimized way of doing such without being vulnerable to the request limit. I also don't believe that the Twitter APIs request limit is easily reached.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? What is your goal at the end of the script.

Comment: My goal is to retrieve a set of tweets for a particular, and for each tweet, retrieve the people who retweeted it. In therefore contains 2 loops (For-Next), one for requesting the user's tweets, and within each tweet return, request for the retweeters.

Comment: Ok - From what I see, you are using `$getfieldReTweets` and this variable is not declared. Also, `$requestMethodReTweets` is not declared. Fix this first.

Comment: thanks David. those two variables are actually declared and values are set way up in my code. so rest assured, i believe these values are OK. :-) i am only pasting here the main block of codes. but will update my post to avoid confusion. thanks. :-)